# Script that copies files from a certain folder to a new one and renames them consecutevly while skipping certain numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello I used ChatGpt to generate a script that copies certain files from a parent folder to a new one using a .txt file as a guide. The Script worked but I tried to push it a little more and give the script some numbers to avoid when renaming and got this script which copies the files but ignores the forbidden numbers. He gave some other solutions when prompted but none of them worked.
Maybe someone could help please ? I dont have much knowlegde in programing (I am a land surveyor) and cant figure out by myself what is wrong.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I wasted you're time !

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Change working directory to the location of the batch script
PUSHD "%~dp0"

REM Debug Information: Display the current directory to verify the script location
echo Current Directory: "%cd%"

REM Update the source of files2.txt to include the parent directory of the script
SET "file_list=%~dp0files2.txt"

SET "src=D:\............."
SET "dst=D:\............."
SET "out=result.log"
echo. > "%out%"

echo Source folder: "%src%"
echo Destination folder: "%dst%"

REM Debug Information: List the files in the current directory to verify the presence of files2.txt
echo Files in the current directory:
dir /b "%cd%"

REM Check if files2.txt exists
IF EXIST "%file_list%" (
    REM Initialize the starting number for renaming
    SET "rename_number=1"

    REM Create a list of skipped numbers as a semicolon-separated string
    SET "skipped_numbers=1;6;12;15"

    REM Convert the semicolon-separated string into an array-like format
    SET "skip_index=0"
    FOR %%N IN (%skipped_numbers%) DO (
        SET "skip_array[!skip_index!]=%%N"
        SET /A "skip_index+=1"
    )

    REM Function to check if a rename number is skipped
    :CheckSkippedNumber
    FOR %%N IN (%skipped_numbers%) DO (
        IF "!rename_number!"=="%%N" (
            SET /A "rename_number+=1"
            GOTO CheckSkippedNumber
        )
    )

    REM Process each line in files2.txt
    FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%f IN ("%file_list%") DO (
        SET "filename=%%f"
        SET "source_file=%src%\!filename!"
        IF EXIST "!source_file!" (
            REM Check if the filename already exists in the dictionary
            IF DEFINED filename_dict (
               REM If the filename is a duplicate, append a unique identifier
                IF NOT DEFINED filename_dict[!filename!] (
                    SET "filename_dict[!filename!]=1"
                ) ELSE (
                    SET "filename_dict[!filename!]=!rename_number!"
                    SET "destination_file=%dst%\!filename:~0,-4!_!filename_dict[!filename!]!%%~xf"
                    CALL :CheckSkippedNumber
                )
            ) ELSE (
                SET "destination_file=%dst%\!rename_number!%%~xf"
                CALL :CheckSkippedNumber
            )

            echo "!source_file!" ^> "!destination_file!" >> "%out%"
            @copy /y "!source_file!" "!destination_file!" 
        ) ELSE (
            echo "!filename!" is not found in the source folder. >> "%out%"
        )
     )
) ELSE (
    echo %file_list% not found!
)

echo Done processing files.
pause

REM Restore the original working directory
POPD
exit /b

:CheckSkippedNumber
REM Increment the rename_number for the next file
SET /A "rename_number+=1"

REM Check if the incremented number is in the skipped list
FOR %%N IN (%skipped_numbers%) DO (
    IF "!rename_number!"=="%%N" GOTO CheckSkippedNumber
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not here to fix code generated by ChatGPT. Please read [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).